# Status of daemonized MCE process affects parent process

Tags: linux, perl, parallel-processing

I'm using MCE to do some things and it's been working well. I need to watch for an event to occur then fork an MCE process to process that event. This works well, but I've run into a problem where an error in the child process kills the parent process when I think only the child MCE process should be affected. Here is a short program that demonstrates this behavior.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use MCE::Loop;
use MCE::Signal '-setpgrp';
use POSIX "setsid";

$SIG{CHLD} = 'IGNORE';

my $mce_maxWorkers = 2;
my $mce_chunkSize = 1;
my @pids;
my $i = 0;

my $name = shift;

while ($i < 2) {
    my $pid = fork();

    if (!defined $pid) {
        print "Can't fork: $!\n";
    }

    elsif ($pid == 0) {

        #setpgrp(0,0);
        (setsid() != -1) || die "Can't start a new session: $!";

        MCE::Loop::init {
            max_workers => $mce_maxWorkers,
            chunk_size => $mce_chunkSize,
            on_post_exit => sub {
                my ($mce, $e) = @_;
                print "$e->{wid}: $e->{pid}: status $e->{status}: $e->{msg}\n";
            }
        };

        my $tail = 'tail -q -f '.$name;
        open my $tail_fh, "-|", $tail or die "Can't open tail\n";

        mce_loop_f {
            my ($mce, $chunk_ref, $chunk_id) = @_;
            my $line = ${$chunk_ref}[0];
            chomp($line);
            print $line."\n";

        } $tail_fh;
        close $tail_fh;

        MCE->shutdown;
        exit;
    }

    else {
        print $pid."\n";
        $i++;
        push(@pids,$pid);
    }
}

foreach my $p (@pids) {
    waitpid $p, 0;
}
```

When run this program forks two children processes that tail a file and read its contents with an MCE loop that has two worker processes. This results in 7 processes, 1 parent, 2 MCE managers, and 4 MCE workers (and 2 tail processes).

Using setsid, the MCE manager processes should be decoupled from the parent process. Anything that causes these children to die should not affect the parent process correct?

Here are the results of ps -efj | grep monitor

```
user1  29001   978 29001   978  0 11:41 pts/2    00:00:00 /usr/bin/perl ./monitor1_test.pl tmp/monitor1/test1.log
user1  29002 29001 29002 29002  0 11:41 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/perl ./monitor1_test.pl tmp/monitor1/test1.log
user1  29003 29001 29003 29003  0 11:41 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/perl ./monitor1_test.pl tmp/monitor1/test1.log
user1  29004 29002 29002 29002  0 11:41 ?        00:00:00 tail -q -f tmp/monitor1/test1.log
user1  29005 29003 29003 29003  0 11:41 ?        00:00:00 tail -q -f tmp/monitor1/test1.log
user1  29006 29002 29002 29002  0 11:41 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/perl ./monitor1_test.pl tmp/monitor1/test1.log
user1  29007 29002 29002 29002  0 11:41 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/perl ./monitor1_test.pl tmp/monitor1/test1.log
user1  29008 29003 29003 29003  0 11:41 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/perl ./monitor1_test.pl tmp/monitor1/test1.log
user1  29009 29003 29003 29003  0 11:41 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/perl ./monitor1_test.pl tmp/monitor1/test1.log
```

If I were to send a SIGTERM to 29002 above, I would expect that process to die along with 29004, 29006, and 29007. I also would expect process 29001 and 29003 to remain unaffected.

However, what I see is that 29001 dies along with 29002 while 29003 remains. The following error is observed on the terminal.

```
shell $ ./monitor1_test.pl tmp/monitor1/test1.log 
29002
29003
test1234
test1234

## monitor1_test.pl: caught signal (INT), exiting

Killed
shell $ MCE::shutdown: method cannot be called while running at /usr/share/perl5/site_perl/MCE/Signal.pm line 371.
END failed--call queue aborted at ./monitor1_test.pl line 371, <$tail_fh> line 1.
```

Why would the termination of one of the children processes affect the parent in this manner? Am I doing something wrong or making an incorrect assumption that the parent should live through this? I'm a bit vexed at the moment so any advice would be very much appreciated.

Platform: Linux 4.0.6 x86_64
Perl: 5.22

Comment: You send SIGTERM, but the parent received SIGINT?

Comment: `kill('INT', $_is_MSWin32 ? -$$ : -getpgrp);` in  MCE::Signal probably responsible.

Comment: @ikegami Thanks you're correct. I hacked away at Signal.pm and there are a number of instances where the process group is killed and there are references to $main_proc_id (the parent pid) in those kills as well. I'm sure there's a proper way around it, but this looks to be the root cause. Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't calling `setpgrp` do the trick?

Comment: I tried that early on (comment still in script above), but the issue persisted. The issue appears related to the fact that MCE::Signal assigns HUP, INT, QUIT, and TERM to \&stop_and_exit. To get the functionality I was looking for I had to use setpgrp in the child process *and* set $SIG{TERM} back to DEFAULT in my script. This allowed me to terminate the child process group without affecting the parent.

Comment: The root cause of this may be related to the following that's in &stop_and_exit: if ($_no_kill9 == 1 || $_sig_name eq 'PIPE') { kill('INT', $_is_MSWin32 ? -$$ : -getpgrp); } else { kill('KILL', -$$, $main_proc_id);} In my test case, $main_proc_id is set to the parent process so when it gets to this line it's sending a KILL to the parent. Perhaps this explains it. As a workaround I'm just taking TERM and INT back in my program so this doesn't occur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The module caches the PID on module load. Fix it by performing the following post-fork:

```
$MCE::Signal::main_proc_id = $$;
```

Better yet, delay loading of MCE until after the fork. I'd do that by moving

```
use MCE::Loop;
use MCE::Signal '-setpgrp';
```

into a module (say `Worker.pm`), and by moving the child code into a sub named `run` in that same module, then perform the following post-fork:

```
require Worker;
Worker::run();
```

---

`script`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use POSIX qw( setsid );

my $name = shift;

my @pids;
while (@pids < 2) {
    my $pid = fork();

    if (!defined $pid) {
        print "Can't fork: $!\n";
    }

    elsif ($pid == 0) {
        (setsid() != -1)
            or die "Can't start a new session: $!";

        require Worker;
        Worker::run($name);
        exit;
    }

    else {
        print $pid."\n";
        push(@pids, $pid);
    }
}

for my $pid (@pids) {
    waitpid($pid, 0);
}
```

`Worker.pm`:

```
package Worker;

use strict;
use warnings;

use MCE::Loop;
use MCE::Signal '-setpgrp';

my $mce_maxWorkers = 2;
my $mce_chunkSize  = 1;

sub run {
    my $name = shift;

    MCE::Loop::init {
        max_workers => $mce_maxWorkers,
        chunk_size => $mce_chunkSize,
        on_post_exit => sub {
            my ($mce, $e) = @_;
            print "$e->{wid}: $e->{pid}: status $e->{status}: $e->{msg}\n";
        }
    };

    my $tail = 'tail -q -f '.$name;
    open my $tail_fh, "-|", $tail or die "Can't open tail\n";

    mce_loop_f {
        my ($mce, $chunk_ref, $chunk_id) = @_;
        my $line = ${$chunk_ref}[0];
        chomp($line);
        print $line."\n";

    } $tail_fh;
    close $tail_fh;

    MCE->shutdown;
}

1;
```

Comment: I had to add package Worker; to the top of Worker.pm (I renamed it), but otherwise this works perfectly! Thanks for taking the time to work through it with me. I'll be able to take this and implement it into my main program pretty quickly. :)

Comment: argh, second time I forgot that this week. Fixed.